How to remove Preload?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I just wanted to know that how to remove Preload completely from my machine.I have searched for it online but I did not find any solution to that. Also I am new to Linux/Ubuntu so please help me out.

What is preload and how did you install it?

To remove preload and its configuration files completely from all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:
sudo apt purge preload

